# Drag resize a div contained in another with padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to resize a div exactly like here on stackoverflow editor (at the bottom of the editor).

Everything works fine until I position my div in another div with a padding.

contained in a div :

[contained in div](http://jsfiddle.net/activee/fcoerd0t)

I'm using this to drag the div. Note that it is working until I have a padding in my main div.

```
$('#drag').mousedown(function(e){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
         $('#iframeEditorContainer').css("height",e.pageY);
    })
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

and then I made it working by changing a line in js:
[working](http://jsfiddle.net/activee/fcoerd0t/2/)

```
$('#iframeEditorContainer').css("height",e.pageY-80);
```

I did -80 to Y to counter the padding. The problem is that I don't trust this -80, I did it through trial and error and if something happens to change on my page I'm afraid it will mess the dragger up. Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: Or you can just use the [native resize mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) `resize: vertical` to achieve this, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/pb0wn12j/).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm actually coming from that and now want a bar at the bottom for more swag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/fcoerd0t/3/

Get the height between the top of the page and the div.

```
$('#drag').mousedown(function(e){
    var top = $('#iframeEditorContainer').offset().top;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
         $('#iframeEditorContainer').css("height",e.pageY-top);
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

This way, you will always be calculating the height of the `#iframeEditorContainer`

Comment: Thank you ! I'm actually started jquery this evening and didn't know about offset.